# Remove subtitle/caption from hls and dash manifest file

Tags: http-live-streaming, m3u8, mpeg-dash, aws-media-convert, video-subtitles

I am currently using aws mediaconvert to encode videos to hls and dash format. I believe that in the m3u8 (for hls) and mpd (for dash) file which is generated, these can be parsed to remove required subtitles. I am looking to parse the m3u8 and mpd file, create an updated manifest without required subtitles and save it back to s3. Has someone previously done something similar?

Answer (score 1):

This could be done with a Lambda Function triggered by the arrival of the source manifest in a specified S3 bucket.  A Lambda script could remove the captions line(s) and post a revised manifest to the different S3 bucket. The script should then copy the segments over to the new bucket as well in order to maintain a playable HLS or DASH file group.

Alternatively you can ingest the asset as-is into MediaPackage as a VOD asset, and use the '?aws.manifestfilter=subtitle_language:xxx' filter when asking for the VOD manifest. This feature of MediaPackage returns a customized (filtered) version of the source manifest on demand without you having to permanently alter it.  Specifying a filter of 'subtitle_language:zzz' will return a manifest with no subtitles in it. You could also ask for only specified subtitle renditions to be included.